# Excel VBA straight connector issue

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to change straight connector width (arrow pointing towards left), but when I code it to increase length its length is increasing from tail , not from arrowhead.

[image: straight connector]

So is there a way to increase width from arrow head ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could move it after changing size using code similar to this:

```
With ActiveSheet.Shapes("ShapeName")
   .Left = 0
   .Top = 0
End With
```

I know it doesn't answer your question directly, but maybe it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The direction of the arrow is of little relevance. When you change a shape, it is done by either size or position. If you increase the size it'll grow to the right and down. To compensate for this, you will have to move it up and left the same amount.